# Simple Regex to make many zeros to single zero if no trailing digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove any digits before `'$'` symbol.
I want to remove any `'0' ','` digits after `$` symbol.
 But i don't want to remove `'0's` if string is mentioned only like `'$00' or '$0'`.

This is my Regex: `home_value.replace(/,|(\d*\$0*)|(^0)*/g, '');`
I want to remove all `0's` and `'$', ','` symbols from the below mentioned strings. But lets say if user enter `'$0' or '$000'` ..it should be convert to `'0'`

```
0045$002,34234 = 234234
$000300 = 300
$000387687 = 387687
$000 = 0
$00 = 0
$0 = 0
```

Comment: So... `300` will turn into `3`?

Comment: Why is the first one removing the `45`??? Your description doesn't indicate that.

Comment: but it does remove the previous part of 45 with my regex `\d*\$0*` will take care of it

Comment: I'm asking if that's what you intend. Your description doesn't say anything about removing those numbers but your result shows them removed, so the  criteria isn't clear.

Comment: `/\d*\$0*(0?\d*)/g, "$1"`

Answer (score 4):

There's an easier way to do this than with one regex, since you're just after the dollar amount:

```
var stripExcessNumbers = function (n) {
    return parseInt(String(n).split("$")[1].replace(/[^\d]/g, ""), 10);
}
```

This should work so long as your numbers don't get too large.

**test cases**

```js
var stripExcessNumbers = function (n) {
  return parseInt(String(n).split("$")[1].replace(/[^\d]/g, ""), 10);
}

var tests = "0045$002,34234 $000300 $000387687 $000 $00 $0".split(" ")
  , answers = [234234, 300, 387687, 0, 0, 0]

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  document.write("<p>" + stripExcessNumbers(tests[i]) +
    ", correct answer: " + answers[i] + "</p>");
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? This solution clearly works and is better than what the OP is looking to do.

Comment: That's smart that it deals with the superfluous zeros by converting it to a number type. But based on OPs requirements, there is an unstated possibility that your solution either accounts for or works against, which is non numeric characters following the dollar sign token, like `12300$001xx123` or `$xx9x1`. Your approach would return `1123` and `91` while the OP may only want first or last grouping of valid numbers(so 9 vs 1 in second example), or only valid numbers directly following dollar sign (so 1 for first example and 0 for second).

Comment: But that will be up to the OP to decide, I just wanted to raise the point they the answer assumes capturing all digits following token as the needed value

Comment: If you don't want to capture all groups, just remove the `.replace("/[^\d]/g…` part. Then it'll only covert the first group after the dollar sign to a number.

Comment: Does `parseint` return NaN or 0 for nonnumeric input? And in the case of `x$abc123` would it be 0/NaN or 123?

Comment: @Anthony `parseInt("x$abc123")` returns `NaN`. So, if you're only after the first capture group, use `parseInt(String(n).split("$")[1].replace(/^[^\d]*/, ""), 10)`; e.g., `parseInt("x$abc123".split("$")[1].replace(/^[^\d]*/, ""), 10)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^.*\$(0)0*$|.*\$0*|,
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK3tS1/2)**

Look at the substitution section, you have this output:

```
234234
300
387687
0
0
0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
s = '2342$08934200'
+s.substr(s.indexOf('$')+1) // 8934200

s = '$0000'
+s.substr(s.indexOf('$')+1) // 0
```

Comment: this doesn't lose ',' commas

Comment: `0045$002,34234` evaluates as `NaN` through this method.

Comment: The rule about commas wasn't clear in the original question. I explained how to fix that in a comment. Just remove commas first.